# Basic software for any chess enthusiast

Tags: software

What is the beginner's starter pack you would recommend for any chess enthusiast?

I am not asking for any specific product just the general software category.

For example I think everyone should have a:

**chess engine**,

a **graphical chess board** (preferably one that supports XBoard and UCI protocol),

and a **chess database** (like SCID).

Anything, I am missing here?

Answer (score 4):

**Interactive tutorials**, for example presenting a game with commentary and periodically asking you to provide input, e.g. what you think is the best move, how to exploit a mistake etc.

**Passive tutorials** where you just look at the screen. Youtube is best placed for this.

**Set up a position and play against the computer** is great for setting up endgames and taking resigned positions from master games and playing them against the engine. After all, the hardest thing to do in chess is to win a won game.

**Online arena** for playing against real opponents under various time controls.

**Mini games** such as knight's tour, pawn wars etc. to practice key skills such as visualisation and endgame technique.

Comment: Thank you for the list, I might have taken some time to discover all the tools myself. Too mush software variety is some times a bad thing.

Answer (score 1):

I think a **tactics trainer** is definitely great to have. While there are many available online, having an offline tactics trainer is useful when I'm on the go.

Comment: Basically, one that gives you puzzles to solve?

Comment: An older version of CT-ART helped me go from ~1200 to ~1800 a couple years ago. I haven't tried the latest version yet, however: http://chessok.com/shop/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=7_26_44&products_id=610

Comment: I would prefer free and open source software. I can not buy that, might find a crack though. ;)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the software listed, I would add the web site http://www.chessgames.com/ -- It has a setup that lends itself quite well to teaching you the things you'd learn from software:

- Game collections with a game viewer.
- Ability to comment on and read others' comments on games.
- A "guess the move" page to train on selecting the next move in some great historical chess games.

FULL DISCLOSURE - the site is "freemium" so although many features are free, you can if you choose sign up for their paid membership. I paid for it, but whether you do is up to you.

Good luck.